# How do I check if a directory is locked or not in bash?

Tags: bash, osx, lock

I have only been able to find solutions for files, and not directories, like `lsof`. `chflags` has no read option, so I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Locking scheme used for directory operations is based on two
kinds of locks - per-inode (->i_mutex) and per-filesystem
(->s_vfs_rename_mutex).

When taking the i_mutex on multiple non-directory objects, we
always acquire the locks in order by increasing address.  We'll call
that "inode pointer" order in the following.

For our purposes all operations fall in 5 classes:

1) read access.  Locking rules: caller locks directory we are accessing.

2) object creation.  Locking rules: same as above.

3) object removal.  Locking rules: caller locks parent, finds victim,
locks victim and calls the method.

4) rename() that is *not* cross-directory.  Locking rules: caller locks
the parent and finds source and target.  If target already exists, lock
it.  If source is a non-directory, lock it.  If that means we need to
lock both, lock them in inode pointer order.

5) link creation.  Locking rules:
    * lock parent
    * check that source is not a directory
    * lock source
    * call the method.

6) cross-directory rename.  The trickiest in the whole bunch.  Locking
rules:
    * lock the filesystem
    * lock parents in "ancestors first" order.
    * find source and target.
    * if old parent is equal to or is a descendent of target
        fail with -ENOTEMPTY
    * if new parent is equal to or is a descendent of source
        fail with -ELOOP
    * If target exists, lock it.  If source is a non-directory, lock
      it.  In case that means we need to lock both source and target,
      do so in inode pointer order.
    * call the method.

You may write a script that can check directory locking by using some info from the above 6 operations on dir.